# cant get my bftech radio to program with chirp software

Tags: radio-programming

I have a bftech bf-f8rt and they dont show that radio on chirp will they update chirp for that radio? Is there another place like chirp to program it or do i have to do it manual

Comment: Hello Keith, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

Baofeng's [web page for the BFTECH BF-F8RT](https://baofengtech.us/index.php/product/bf-f8rt-2-pcs/) says "You can use Chirp to program the BF-F8RT radio. Please select the Baofeng UV-5X model and program it."  So I'd think that CHIRP is the way to go.

However, [CHIRP's home page](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home) says nothing about the BF-F8RT.  Usually the volunteers who update the CHIRP software and its web page are good about listing every model that has been successfully tested with CHIRP, even if the solution is just to use the setting for a different radio model, as often happens.  Also there is no such thing as a Baofeng "UV-5X".

Aha, there is a link next to the listing for the Baofeng UV-5R on the CHIRP home page, for a page specifically about [UV-5R variants](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Baofeng_UV5R_Variants).  The UV-5R and its many variants are probably the HT model in most common use worldwide.  That page says,

> The Baofeng UV-5R is the basis for many other models. Any vendor that
> purchases a large quantity of radios can have a private label (and in
> some cases, firmware version) applied to the radio. There is, in most
> cases, almost no actual difference between the variants, which is very
> confusing for customers.

The page goes on to list "BF-F8/BF-F8+" as a known UV-5R variant.

So the information is incomplete and confusing.  You could always ask the question on the CHIRP mailing list, which is followed by many people who are better-informed such things than I am.

If someone gave me a BF-F8RT, I would try using CHIRP with the UV-5R setting.  If you try it there's a small chance that you'll "brick" the radio (i.e. break the radio permanently and make it only useful as a paper weight or door stop, like a brick), but if the software really doesn't support your radio then most likely you would just get an error message.

If you do try it, please come back here and let us know what your results were.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so yes I have seen this problem alot, Its a very complicated process, but it can be done. Just about any Baofeng radio can be programmed with chirp software, but its just a matter of figuring it out. When a friend had previously encountered this problem, I showed him this website down below, and it helped him out.

https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Home

Hope this eased some stress.